# Vizframe Datalabel show for one Line

Tags: sapui5

I'm using Vizframe component where there is two lines, when I try to show the Datalabel, the modifications is applied to both lines, I want to apply it just to one of them (A line with Datalabel set to True and a line with DataLabel set to False.)
[Here's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDaSf.png)

This is how I change DataLabel property:

```
plotArea: {
    dataLabel: {
        visible: false
        },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I know that this question might be older, but I had a similar issue recently. You can use the [renderer function](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/vizdocs/index.html#reference/chartProperty/Charts/Combination%20%20(10)/Combined%20Column%20Line%20Chart/) to customize the data labels to your needs.

For me, it worked, when I checked the context data for the correct measure and decide then, if I return nothing, which shows the label normally or return an empty DOM node.

```js
dataLabel: {
    visible: true,
    style: {
        color: "#000"
    },
    renderer: function (ctx) {
        var node = document.createElement("text");
        if (ctx.ctx.measureNames === "Optimum") {
            var text = document.createTextNode("");
            node.appendChild(text);
            return node;
        }
    }
},
```

As you can see in the picture below, the label for the orange line (Optimum) is gone.

[image: Result of the combined chart with bar and line]

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the values when they are overlapped using this:

```js
plotArea: {
    dataLabel: {
        visible: true,
        hideWhenOverlap: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Julian's answer is useful yet in order for the change to take effect on the document we need to attach the returned node to the parent data point node.
The renderer function does not provide data regarding the graph itself but only the selected label, which leaves us clueless on how to render the node effectively.
Something like this would make me happier:

```
renderer: function(...) {
    var parent = document.getElementById(some_given_data_point_id);
    parent.appendChild(text_node);
    return parent;
}
```