# Data label not rendered on sapui5 viz dual y-axis graph when line and column intersect

Tags: javascript, html, svg, charts, sapui5

I have a requirement to show data labels of two graphs on the same axes.
Only when they intersect, one of the two labels won't show. This can be demonstrated below:
[image: Data labels on graph intersection]

As you can see on the 2nd, 5th and 6th columns from the left with values 0%, 7% and 8% respectively
only the orange line values are shown but the blue column values are missing.

This is the final html of the graph after rendering:

[image: Missing labels]

So data-datapoint-id 142, 145 and 146 are missing from the html.

I tried using the [plotArea.dataLabel.renderer function](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/vizdocs/index.html#reference/chartProperty/Charts/Combination%20%20(10)/Combined%20Column%20Line%20Chart/) as a manipulation of what was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72185903/10703543) but nothing changed, still not rendering.

Anyone encountered a similar problem? Is that a sapui5 issue or can it be fixed by manually inserting the labels into the HTML if so how?

Thanks,
Ori

Answer (score 0):

Using [SVG text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) and jQuery I managed to manually insert the labels into the top middle of the blue rectangle columns.

This is the result, not perfect but works:

[image]
and this is the code:

```
chart.setVizProperties({
            plotArea: {
                dataLabel: {
                    formatString: {'פחת כללי': FIORI_PERCENTAGE_FORMAT_2},
                    renderer: function (oLabel) {
                        // Create empty text node to be returned by the function such that the label won't be rendered automatically
                        var node = document.createElement("text");
                        if (oLabel.ctx.measureNames === "כמות פחת כללי") {
                            var kamutLabelIdx = oLabel.ctx._context_row_number;
                            // Use jQuery and SVG to manipulate the HTML
                            var kamutLabelQuery = '[data-id=\"' + kamutLabelIdx + '\"]';
                            var kamutColumn = $(kamutLabelQuery)[0];
    
                            // Create text element as child of the column
                            kamutColumn.innerHTML += "<text>" + oLabel.text + "</text>";

                            var labelNode = $(kamutLabelQuery += ' text');
                            // Set the label position to be at the middle of the column
                            const labelLength = 60;
                            const xPos = (labelLength + oLabel.dataPointWidth) / 2;
                            const yPos = oLabel.styles['font-size'];
                            labelNode.attr({
                                "textLength" : labelLength,
                                "x" : xPos,
                                "y" : yPos,
                                "font-size" : yPos
                            });

                            return node;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

The oLabel parameter of the renderer function provides useful info about the data label to be created:

[image]

I still wonder if that's a bug with sapui5 vizframe and if there is a simpler way to do this.
Please let me know of your thoughts